# XML vs JSON. Which one is better for storing small chunk of data?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, json

I want to store some small chunk of data and don't want to go for any database, we have two choices `XML` and `JSON`, now anyone can please suggest which one should I select from performance and architecture point of view.

**1. which is better to use? XML or JSON for storing data?**

**2. What are the pros and cons for both JSON and XML?**

any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*

We are not using any web service, our application is a stand alone app. We want to use XML or JSON for storing some local data which will be used in the application. The data would be like details of questions and answers, static userdetails etc.

Comment: see this link <http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-andbene1/index.html>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please keep in mind that JSON is only smaller if the tags are longer than the data.
  Probably the fact that the XML is a lot easier to read, and that JSON has a smaller footprint.

**XML Pros**

- Easier to read
- Used a lot more than JSON
- One of the main industry standards
- Versioning possible
- Namespace support
- Multiple elements with the same name
- Validation

**XML Cons**

- Takes up more space
- Increased bandwidth because of the size

**JSON Pros**

- Doesn't take up a lot of space
- Uses less bandwidth because of it's size (footprint)
- Rising in the ranks as one of the main industry standards

**JSON Cons**

- Harder to read
- Versioning breaks client/data

If you are sending more data than you send tags then they are about the same and you would have been better off using XML for the fast parsing speeds. I would also argue that people expect slow mobile load times and fast app running times so try and not slow down the app time by using a slower format to parse.

Finally I say **JSON**, The small footprint will speed up transactions between your app and the web services you're trying to send/receive data to/from.

Answer (score 8):

JSON is the best way to design any mobile application development, because parsing JSON is very light weight operation compare to XML. while XML parsing is always leads to complex memory problem. and JSON can be easily build/parse with GSON library which is again very light weight.

XML Parsing will be head ache if you have different versions of parsers to use. so go for JSON.

Answer (score 6):

Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a text format derived from Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML).

Most of the excitement around XML is around a new role as an interchangeable data serialization format. XML provides two enormous advantages as a data representation language:

```
It is text-based.
It is position-independent.
```

These together encouraged a higher level of application-independence than other data-interchange formats. The fact that XML was already a W3C standard meant that there wasn't much left to fight about (or so it seemed).

Unfortunately, XML is not well suited to data-interchange, much as a wrench is not well-suited to driving nails. It carries a lot of baggage, and it doesn't match the data model of most programming languages. When most programmers saw XML for the first time, they were shocked at how ugly and inefficient it was. It turns out that that first reaction was the correct one. There is another text notation that has all of the advantages of XML, but is much better suited to data-interchange. That notation is JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).

The most informed opinions on XML (see for example xmlsuck.org) suggest that XML has big problems as a data-interchange format, but the disadvantages are compensated for by the benefits of interoperability and openness.

JSON promises the same benefits of interoperability and openness, but without the disadvantages.

Rest of the comparison is [here](http://www.json.org/xml.html).